# How do I implement audio controls on this audio visualizer that uses HTML5 Web Audio API?

Tags: javascript, php, html, audio, web-audio-api

I know how put audio controls when you're importing the source of the audio like so:

```
  <audio src="audio.mp3" id="audio" controls="true"></audio>
```

What's different about the audio visualizer that im trying to fiddle with is that it uses the audio, that the user has to upload (test the demo below). What I would like to know is- how can I put audio controls so that I can play, pause, next/previous song, volume(with mute and unmute), and a loop button(if selected, it loops the current played/uploaded audio file) the audio file?

And of course if the audio stops, im assuming the visualizer will stop too? I wouldn't know because I don't know how to put audio controls.

Index.php code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <meta name="description" content="HTML5 Audio Spectrum Visualizer">
    <title>HTML5 Audio API showcase | Audio visualizer</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="fileWrapper" class="file_wrapper">
            <div id="info">
                HTML5 Audio API showcase | An Audio Viusalizer
            </div>
            <label for="uploadedFile">Drag&drop or select a file to play:  
</label>
            <input type="file" id="uploadedFile"></input>
        </div>
        <div id="visualizer_wrapper">
            <canvas id='canvas' width="800" height="350"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <small></small>
    </footer>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/html5_audio_visualizer.js">    
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The full javascript file (long) :

https://github.com/wayou/HTML5_Audio_Visualizer/blob/master/js/html5_audio_visualizer.js

That's all I wanted to know.

Thanks.

Original Author & Code(css included): 
https://github.com/wayou/HTML5_Audio_Visualizer
Demo: http://wayou.github.io/HTML5_Audio_Visualizer/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the `_visualize` method on line 125 of the source. In the method the `audioBufferSourceNode` holds the file that has been loaded.

on line 136 the `start()` and `stop()` methods are being used on the audio node. If you get a reference to the `audioBufferSourceNode` out of the library you can call these methods to play and pause the sound.

Comment: so what would I have to do to the  start() and stop()  methods?